# CMIS aspect query with path

Tags: alfresco, cmis, alfresco-enterprise

I need to query a particular folder in the repository using a java based scheduler in alfresco.

I need to check whether the custom aspect's property is present or not.

Below query works for me when I don't use the path query.

```
select * from myType:caseDoc as d join myAspect:caseId as s on d.cmis:objectId = s.cmis:objectId
```

The problem with the above query is it searches all the contents in the repository but I want to target a particular folder.

When I try to put the CONTAINS in the above query it fails.

```
select * from cch:caseDoc as d
join cch:caseId as s on d.cmis:objectId = s.cmis:objectId WHERE CONTAINS('PATH:"//app:company_home/cm:FWED/cm:CDO/cm:CAB-DROP-FOLDER/*"')
```

It gives below exception
A selector must be specified when there are two or more selectors

Thank you

Comment: It looks like you may be missing one argument in CONTAINS(). Did you try something like this? 
 

    select * 
      from cch:caseDoc as d 
      join cch:caseId as s 
        on d.cmis:objectId = s.cmis:objectId 
    WHERE 
      CONTAINS(d,'PATH:"//app:company_home/cm:FDLE/cm:CCH/cm:CCH-DROP-FOLDER/*"')

Comment: why not getting folder with a java method since you are using CMIS

Comment: If I get the folder by using java method then I need to get all its child and filter it by looping it. I think it will be very costly process in terms of memory and time.

Comment: @luiscolorado it worked well Thanks!

I am just struggling with a small thing like a string value is black when I see from CMIS Workbench. but when I put condition at the end any of the below not working..

AND p.acc:cNumber <> ''  gives Request failed 500 eroror 

02170080 Request failed 500 /solr4/alfresco/cmis?wt=json&fl=DBID%2Cscore&rows=100&df=TEXT&start=0&locale=en&alternativeDic=DEFAULT_DICTIONARY&cmisVersion=CMIS_1_1&fq=%7B%21afts%7DAUTHORITY_FILTER_FROM_JSON&fq=%


AND p.acc:cNumber IS NOT NULL (return the row with blank cNumber)

Comment: Sam, I'd suggest putting that problem in a separate question. Is '' two apostrophes or a single quote?

Comment: Yes, I did it. Thanks!
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42903935/alfresco-cmis-query-checking-for-null-blank?noredirect=1#comment72961263_42903935

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you may be missing one argument in CONTAINS(). Did you try something like this?

```
select * 
  from cch:caseDoc as d 
    join cch:caseId as s 
    on d.cmis:objectId = s.cmis:objectId 
WHERE CONTAINS(d,'PATH:"//app:company_home/cm:FDLE/cm:CCH/cm:CCH-D‌​ROP-FOLDER/*"')
```

(I'm just putting my comment as an answer)

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you are worrying about the path, then you should put

```
CONTAINS('PATH:"/app:company_home/cm:FWED/cm:CDO/cm:CAB-DROP-FOLDER/*"')
```

With one single `/` at the start of the path, if you which to only search in direct children to that path or :

```
CONTAINS('PATH:"/app:company_home/cm:FWED/cm:CDO/cm:CAB-DROP-FOLDER//*"')
```

to perform the lookup in the whole underlying hierarchy!

However, I do think that the query you provided and the behaviour you described does not match each other !